# Is Q(4th root(2))/Q a galois extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I'm having some difficulty with the definition for galois extensions.
The definition as read from my notes is $L/K$ is galois if $L^{Aut(L/K)}= K$. Where $Aut(L/K)$ is definied to be the set of all automorphisms over K, and $L^S:=${$\alpha\in L|\sigma (\alpha)=\alpha \space\space\forall \sigma\in S$}. But then I can't find an extension which isn't galois. Take this example, is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ a galois extension?

Comment: No it is not, the automorphism group of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)/\Bbb Q$ fixes $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ pointwise.

Comment: I think you should give a look to this [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension#Characterization_of_Galois_extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension#Characterization_of_Galois_extensions)

Comment: Another criterion for a field to be Galois is that the number of automorphisms is the degree of the field extension. In characteristic 0, another alternative definition is to say a field extension is Galois if it is *normal*, which means that if an irreducible polynomial $f \in K[X]$ has a root in $L$, then all of its roots lie in $L$ (I.e. Over $L$, the polynomial factors into linear terms). So consider the polynomial $X^4 - 2$. This shows that your extension isn't Galois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $a = \sqrt[4]{2}$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(a) / \mathbb{Q}$ is an extension of degree 4.

Consider the automorphism $\sigma \in Aut (\mathbb{Q}(a)/ \mathbb{Q} )$ which sends $a \mapsto -a$. Then $a^2 = \sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ is a fixed element of $\sigma$.

Comment: oh ok, can I also ask what the size of the automorphism would be in this case, I worked out 4 automorphisms, but forgot to include the possibility that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})=-\sqrt[4]{2}$ or $-z \sqrt[4]{2}$ or $-z^2 \sqrt[4]{2}$ or $-z^3 \sqrt[4]{2}$. Where $z$ is the quartic root of unity

Comment: Well, in this case the group of automorphisms has order 2. Honestly I cannot understand your question in the comment...

Comment: $\sigma ((\sqrt[4]{2})^4)=(\sigma(\sqrt[4]{2}))^4= \sigma(2)=2$, so $\sigma(\sqrt[4]{2})=$ either $\sqrt[4]{2}$ or $z\sqrt[4]{2}$ or $z^2\sqrt[4]{2}$ or $z^3\sqrt[4]{2}$

Comment: Hence, there's 8 possible automorphisms if I include the negative results?

Comment: No. In this extension you have only real roots. So $\sqrt[4]{2}$ can be sent only to itself or to its opposite. In the case you are having all the roots, then you are working with the splitting field, whose degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ is 8.

Comment: Ah I see, because $\forall \sigma\in Aut(L/K) \sigma (\alpha)$ can only be mapped to an element in tge larger field L